# How do I check for corrupt parts in my .blend file?

Tags: blend-files

I have a corrupt .blend file that causes bugs, if I copy/paste into a new file its content will bring the bug along.

The bug emerges in the time stretching, it isn't acting as it should.

Time stretching, with 24 fps, if input old=24, new=72, it renders 24 frames at normal rate then renders the next 50 frames of the last frame.

I tried this mesh checking code but that just spits out hundreds of lines that I have no clue what to make of it.

```
import bpy
for me in bpy.data.meshes:
    me.validate()
```

In the file I have rigs, characters, lights, cameras, textures, props, animation data, etc.

How do I go about making sure all of it is corruption free?